# T.Test with pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have 2 data frames pd and pd2:

pd

```
Name  A   B     Mean
 t1   1.0 2.0    1.5
 t2   2.0 3.0    2.5
 t3   9.4 3.3    6.35
```

pd2

```
Name  A   B     Mean
 t1   1.1 2.7    1.9
 t2   3.7 3.0    3.35
 t3   10.4 4.3   7.35
```

I would like to do the ttest calculation for columns 'A' on both dataframes and column B on both dataframes the result can be added to one of the dataframes or it can be added to a new data frame.  The output should have the columns:

```
ttestA ttestB ttestC ...etc
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html

Comment: I've tried ttestA = ttest_ind(df['A'],df2['A'], equal_var=False) it does work but since I have several columns I'm not sure how to iterate through all as not to include the columns 'Name', 'Mean' and others.

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using for loop

```
from scipy import stats
l=[]
listofname=['A','B']
for x in listofname:
    l.append(stats.ttest_ind(df[x],df2[x], equal_var=False))
```

Comment: That Worked! Thanks.  If I wanted to do this same calculation across all columns for every row I could just use axis=1 correct?